# given an %hhu and an input 1025, which part is mapped to an unsigned char?

Tags: c, scanf, language-lawyer

Is the output of the following programm `1` or `0`, or is it undefined behaviour?

```
int main() {
  unsigned char u = 10;
  sscanf("1025","%hhu",&u);
  printf("u, is it 0 or is it 1? u's value is ... %hhu", u);
}
```

According to `fscanf` [conversion specifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) `%u` with [length modifier](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p11) `hh` (i.e. `%hhu`), semantics is defined based on that of `strtoul` function and a mapping to type pointer to unsigned char:

> 12) The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **"u"**
>   Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same
>   as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the
>   value 10 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to unsigned integer.
>
> 11) The length modifiers and their
>   meanings are:
>
> **"hh"** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x,
>   X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer
>   to signed char or unsigned char.

But what happens if an input sequence represents an integral value exceeding 8 bits, which part of the integral value is mapped to the 8 bits of an unsigned char? Is it defined that it has to be the least significant part, does it depend on endianess, is it unspecified, or does it even yield undefined behaviour?

I cannot believe that it is undefined or unspecified behaviour. This would mean that user input might introduce such behaviour in a program using `scanf("%hhu",&u)`, and checking user input before every use of `scanf` looks absurd to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Undefined. See [one section up:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10)

> 10 Except in the case of a % specifier, the input item (or, in the case of a %n directive, the count of input characters) is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure. Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, **or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: Counterpoint: The result of converting 1025 to `unsigned char` is 1 (6.3.1.3/2). 1 can be represented in `u`.

Comment: @melpomene: Yeah, I thought of that after posting, so now I'm trying to see if there's anything more explicit in the standard.

Comment: @melpomene: I believe the word "conversion" is being used differently here. Yes, a type conversion of the value `1025` to `unsigned char` yields `1` (assuming, e.g., `CHAR_BIT==8`). But the "conversion" being discussed here is from an input item (a sequence of characters) to the target type. The result of that conversion (of the string `"1025"` to an integer) is 1025, which cannot be represented in an `unsigned char` object.

Comment: @melpomene: I agree there is some ambiguity and underspecification here, but I think the conclusion is correct. There is no language to suggest that the conversion takes place first by conversion from a character sequence to an arbitrary-precision integer, then as if by a conversion of integer types. It's suggested (but not clearly stated) that the conversion happens as if by `strtol`-family functions (which don't exist for all types); in that case out-of-bounds values produce errors, not wrapping.

Comment: @R.. The `strtol` stuff only describes the format of the input (in particular, the "subject sequence" of strto(u)l), not the actual conversion/mapping.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm inclined to agree with you (6.3 "Conversions" doesn't apply here). But that means any use of a `scanf` directive (other than `%%` and `%*...`) has undefined behavior, because this "conversion" is not defined anywhere ("*the input item [...] is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier*" and "*An
input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters [...]*"). It's not a number->number or pointer->number conversion. As far as I can tell, its semantics aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: @melpomene: I seems to me that the conversions are defined in 7.21.6.2 (fscanf). For example a `d` conversion specifier "Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtol` function with the value 10
for the `base` argument." It may be that some aspects are not defined explicitly, but the meaning seems clear enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson That gives a sort of arbitrary precision semantics, but it doesn't clarify what "conversion" means in that context. Specifically, in this case we'd have to know how some abstract mathematical integer (which doesn't even have a C type) is converted to an `unsigned char` (or `unsigned int`, etc.). If it is reduced modulo MAX+1 (as usual for unsigned integers), all values are representable; if not, we get UB.

Comment: @melpomene: Reduction modulo MAX+1 is relevant only for type conversions. Since no type conversions occur here, only "conversions" of character sequences to the values they represent, I'd say that an out-of-range value causes UB even for unsigned types. (It might have been helpful if the standard had uses a word other than "conversion".)

Comment: Another thing to consider: "the input item ... is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier". The conversion specifier is specifically the `u` character, and does not include the `hh`. This may be interpreted as saying that the input item is converted to unsigned int, even when the conversion specification is `%hhu`. The result of that conversion would then be `1025u`, a value that cannot be represented in an 8-bit unsigned char.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, but in `%hhu` the `hh` modifier specifies that the `u` conversion specifier takes an `unsigned char`, not an `unsigned int` (somehow the meaning of `u` is mutable and `hh` affects it). However, ambiguities like this just lend more support to my interpretation that any non-trivial use of `scanf` has undefined behavior. :-[

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't make much sense for `%llu` to convert to unsigned int and try to store into an unsigned long long either.

Comment: This is one of the major reasons why I go around saying "never use scanf, it's broken as specified".

Comment: @zwol: seems like `scanf` cannot be used safely even for simple cases of reading in integral values from "unknown" input; I always thought `scanf` to be a widely used function...

Comment: @StephanLechner "Widely used" does not contradict "_should not_ ever be used".